# TokBox number of users in a room or session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, opentok, tokbox

I am new to using TokBox with my Rails app.  I have created my "rooms" and a user can create a "room" and other users can join the room and video conference together  Marvelous!  But how do I know how many users are in a room and which users they are?  I would like to display their information eventually but initially I just need to know how to see who is in the room on pageload.  Any experienced TokBox devs out there?

Comment: Not super experienced, but have used it before - http://bvc-video.herokuapp.com/broadcasts/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any way to see who is in the room on pageload. Once you are connected to a session, you will get a connectionCreated event for every person in the room. To get the number of users in the room, just have a counter that increments for each connectionCreated event that gets triggered.